# Django newly created instance - DateTime field is type 'str'

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, celery

I am using Django 2.2.3 and Celery 4.3.0

One of my celery tasks creates a new instance of one of my django models and saves it. After I have saved that new instance, if i access one of the fields of the saved instance called DateTimeStamp which is a DateTimeField, the value returned is a string object. However, if i return the same instance from the database, the value of DateTimeStamp is a datetime.datetime object.

I also get a RunTimeWarning about the field receiving a naive datetime while timezone support is active, which I know is because i am using timezones in my django app and passing it a datetime which contains no timezone info, however, i would not expect that to cause the behavious i am seeing.

my model in models.py:

```
class StgAvailabilityConfirmation(models.Model):
    ServiceType = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ContractID = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Confirmation = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    FileReason = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    DateTimeStamp = models.DateTimeField()
    status = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

the code in django_tasks.py:

```
new_instance = target_model(**top_level_record)
new_instance.save()
print(top_level_record)
print(new_instance.pk)
created_instance = target_model.objects.get(pk=new_instance.pk)
print(new_instance.DateTimeStamp)
print(type(new_instance.DateTimeStamp))
print(created_instance.DateTimeStamp)
print(type(created_instance.DateTimeStamp))
```

output from worker:

```
[2019-07-24 14:27:32,630: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-16] /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:1421: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField StgAvailabilityConfirmation.DateTimeStamp received a naive datetime (2018-07-25 13:01:00) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
[2019-07-24 14:27:32,670: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-16] {'ServiceType': 'STOR_FLEXIBLE', 'ContractID': '35.41', 'Confirmation': 'ACCEPTED', 'DateTimeStamp': '2018-07-25T13:01:00.000'}
[2019-07-24 14:27:32,670: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-16] 62
[2019-07-24 14:27:32,693: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-16] 2018-07-25T13:01:00.000
[2019-07-24 14:27:32,693: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-16] <class 'str'>
[2019-07-24 14:27:32,693: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-16] 2018-07-25 13:01:00+00:00
[2019-07-24 14:27:32,693: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-16] <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

What is the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: In `target_model(**top_level_record)` you pass datetime as key-value pair where value is string. You can pass datetime object here

Comment: Yes i know i am doing this, but it shouldn't be a problem, for various reasons it is convenient for me to pass a string because the data is a string when i receive it. It is valid to instantiate the instance in this way. The question is why do i see the behaviour i see?

Comment: But what do you mean, "why"? Why would you expect anything different?

Comment: I don't understand why there is a difference between the instance i have created and the instance returned from the database. Are they not (essentially) two references to the same instance of the same class? I have never seen anything in Django documentation which says you must return your newly created instances from the database before you can you use them, if for example they have methods where the type of the DateTImeField is important (please link me if this is documented)

Comment: This is because when you save the `new_instance`, It won't fetch the data from db.
Where as in 2nd case, the data is fetched from the db.
If you want your new_instance to be fetched from db.
Just do 

`new_instance.refresh_from_db()`

Comment: @sp1rs Thank you that makes sense, I didn't occur to me that the save() function would not save the new instance and also refresh it from the db. In fact i'm still not sure why the save function doesn't do this but i'm sure the reasoning has been well thought out by the Django devs.

Comment: @teebagz Just found this after 3 days of googling. I'm puzzled by this as well. If anyone knows the reason why is this happening please share. I do not think that calling `refresh_from_db()` on every object created is a good idea.